# Trying to optimize MySQL query with LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join

I've this query, which works fine except it takes a long while (7 seconds, with 40k records in the jobs table, and 700k in the wq table).

I tried an EXPLAIN and it says its looking at all the records in the job table, and not using any of the indexes.

I don't know how to tell MySQL that it should use the jobs.status field to filter the the records before looking up the wq table.

The objective of this, is to get all the records from jobs that have a status != 331, and also any other job which has a wq status of (101, 111, 151).

Query:

```
SELECT jobs.*
FROM jobs
LEFT OUTER JOIN wq ON (wq.job = jobs.id AND jobs.status IN (341, 331) AND wq.status IN (101, 111, 151))
WHERE ((wq.info is not NULL) or (jobs.status != 331 and ack = 0))
```

EXPLAIN output:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  jobs    ALL     ack,status,status_ack   NULL    NULL    NULL    38111   Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  wq  ref     PRIMARY,job,status  PRIMARY     4   cts.jobs.id     20  Using where
```

Table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE jobs ( id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
comment varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
profile varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
start_at int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
data text NOT NULL,
status int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
info varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
finish int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
priority int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
ack tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (id),
KEY start_at (start_at),
KEY status (status),
KEY status_ack (status,
ack) ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2037530 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE wq ( job int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
process varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
step varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
status int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
run_at int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
original_run_at int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
info varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
pos int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
changed_at int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
file varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (job,
process,
step,
file),
KEY job (job),
KEY status (status) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Can you post the table definitions, too? The `SHOW CREATE TABLE jobs` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE wq`.

Comment: What I know realize is that I'm asking for all the values for jobs.status (one part in the join and the other in the where).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately mysql (and perhaps any dbms) cannot optimize expressions like `jobs.status != 331 and ack = 0` because B-Tree is not a structure that allows to find fast anything that is-not-equal-to-a-constant-value. Thus you'll always get a fullscan.

If there were some better condition like `jobs.status = 331 and ack = 0` (note on the fact that i've changed `!=` to `=`) then it would be an advice to speed up this query:

1. split the query into 2, joined by `UNION ALL`
2. replace in one query `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` (in the one that implies that `wq.info is not NULL`)

Comment: Replacing jobs.status != 331 for jobs.status in (311,321,341) (which are the other possible values) did not help. I don't understand the other options. If I do a UNION, wouldn't that be running two queries and joining the resutls? how can that be faster?

Comment: separating the query with an UNION made it fast:                   `SELECT jobs.*
            FROM jobs,wq
            WHERE (wq.job = jobs.id AND jobs.status IN (341, 331) AND wq.status IN ( 101, 111, 151 ))


            UNION

            SELECT jobs.*
            FROM jobs
            WHERE (1=1)
and (jobs.status in (311, 321, 341) and ack = 0)
`