# MySQL; LEFT OUTER joining on DATEDIFF with indexes taking 300+ seconds (but only the first time)

Tags: mysql, database-performance, datediff

MySQL's built in cache really makes this question moot for most of the day, but the very first time the following query is run, the performance is *terrible*: Taking over 300 seconds the first time whereas subsequent querying can complete in milliseconds. Running this with SQL_NO_CACHE then takes 2-4 seconds (!) which is very acceptable in this instance -- but the initial run-time is not.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF( bt.`datetime`, st.`datetime`) AS 'day_separation'
FROM `smallerTable` AS st
LEFT OUTER JOIN `bigTable` AS bt ON bt.item_id = st.item_id
  AND bt.code = 'X'
  AND bt.`datetime` > st.`datetime`
  AND DATEDIFF ( bt.datetime, st.datetime) < 11
  AND st.`datetime` > '2012-07-01' AND st.`datetime` < 'yesterdays-date 23:59:59'
```

I have introduced multi-column indexes ([thanks to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051246/in-mysql-how-to-build-index-to-speed-up-this-query)) but it still could not address this particular problem. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442420/trying-to-optimize-mysql-query-with-left-outer-join) looks inspired but I don't think it is applicable since I'm not sure how I could union these results.

The smaller table has ~8000 records and I want to count / include all of them right now. It will eventually grow bigger and contain items prior to 2012-07-01.

bigTable has 10 million records and I only want to match the "pairing" of those records to the smaller table. Part of the trouble is that they cannot share a direct key or reference linking them together so I am left with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and guessing that if the timestamp of the two events are < 11 days apart (and share the other conditions) that they they must be related.

Excluding the test `DATEDIFF ( bt.datetime, st.datetime) < 11` created 14k 'results' illustrating that the number of `DATEDIFF` calculations that "*need* to occur" is 14k-8k (a.k.a. 6k).

**INDEXES**: the `datetime` fields of each table, the `code`, and the `item_id`s.

I have compound indexes on both tables in the order of `(item_id, datetime)`. From my understanding, that is the necessary order because we use the datetime fields in the select statement in the form of `DATEDIFF( bt.datetime, st.datetime)`.

**Would a combined index on `(code, item_id, datetime)` revolutionize this query?** (Yes it did!)

The explain reveals little to my untrained eye other than that it is using a temporary table which I understand can be time-consuming.

```
id * select_type * table * type  * possible_keys * key                * key_len * ref           * rows * extra
1  * SIMPLE      * st    * index * NULL          * items_for_datetime * 59      * NULL          * 8295 * using index; using temporary; using filesort
1  * SIMPLE      * BT    * ref   * [many]        * items_for_datetime * 51      * master.st.item_id * 3    *
```

Depending on MySQL's whims, bigTable *sometimes* shows that it prefers the `item_id` key over `items_for_datetime`. Should I encourage the use of my joint index believing that I know better?

Some extra info:

- The inserts into these tables occur once each day (1~5k records into BT)
- No updates or deletions ever occur
- I could probably run two queries -- Change this one to INNER JOIN and then run a second one to subtract the number of results from the total records to find the number that didn't have a corresponding result in BT
- We have already executed phpmyadmin's `Check Table`, `Defragmentation`, and `Optimize Table` on BT

[aside] Could this be a good scenario for using a NoSQL database such as Mongo?

Why is there be such a disparity on the first run and the second? More importantly: **What can be done to improve the timing of the first run?**

**Update:** New attempts require a new day to find out their efficacy. Tomorrow I will attempt Barmar's suggestion using `BETWEEN` and `DATE_ADD`. I have also created a combined index on `(code, item_id, datetime)`. I will report back tomorrow the result but welcome any other ideas.

**Update:** Success! The first run of the query now only spent 6 seconds which is amazing considering where it came from. Subsequent querying took only .035 seconds! What a dream. The combined index on `(code, item_id, datetime)` no doubt had a hand in this success. Here is the new query: Thanks everyone!

```
SELECT DATEDIFF( bt.`datetime`, st.`datetime` ) AS  'day_separation'
FROM  `smallerTable` AS st
LEFT OUTER JOIN bigTable AS bt USE INDEX (  `cmd_item_time` ) 
ON bt.item_id = st.item_id
  AND bt.code =  'X'
  AND bt.`datetime` BETWEEN st.`datetime` AND DATE_ADD( st.`datetime`, INTERVAL 10 DAY ) 
  AND st.datetime BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND  'yesterdays-date 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Indexes on the datetime fields aren't going to help, because you're doing your decision logic based on the result of a function call, not on the underlying fields. If it were possible, you'd have to put an index on `datediff(bt.datetime, st.datetime)`. But you cannot index "derived" results, especially like this, because mysql would have to pregenerate the diff results for EVERY bt/st combination in the table.

Comment: Interesting comment, @MarcB; and would it benefit me to personally generate every bt/st combination -- assuming all the other factors are in agreement? There is _very little_ duplication of `item_id`s as indicated by there only being 6k extra items when I removed the `DATEDIFF` conditional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
AND bt.`datetime` > st.`datetime`
AND DATEDIFF ( bt.datetime, st.datetime) < 11
```

to:

```
AND bt.`datetime` BETWEEN st.`datetime` AND date_add(st.`datetime`, interval 11 day)
```

This may allow the index on `bt.datetime` to be used.

If `code = 'X'` filters out a large portion of `bigTable`, a compound index on `(code, item_id)` should help.

Comment: Thank you Barmar; I will definitely try it out! That looks really cool/creative. Do you have any suggestions about making an 'uber' combined index?

Comment: Barmar, the `EXPLAIN` just told me it plans on using the `item_id` index. Since I only get "one go" of this query per day, would you suggest I just try it or try to force a different index? And, do you think [both of these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128736/mysql-date-add/1128742#1128742) would use the `datetime` index equally as well?

Comment: I guess that means that it can't use the `datetime` index for this type of comparison.

Comment: Aye; when I tried to `USE INDEX (\`datetime\`)` it replied that it would have to do a full table scan and could not apparently use it...does that mean that my combined indexes that include `datetime` will also fail? Should I just leave them out?

Comment: I think that confirms that it's not able to use the datetime index. See my suggestion of a compound `(code, item_id)` index.

Comment: Congratulations, Barmar; because of your assistance and my research the troublesome query just took 6 seconds to execute - in total! An amazing improvement. The query you mention does allow for indexing on the datetimes as mentioned [here](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=377652&seqNum=2) which I 'accidentally' found yesterday. Search for DATE_ADD. My new index of `(code, item_id, datetime)` is successful and is being chosen by MySQL even without my query hint. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem of you query is most probably that line :  AND st.`datetime` > '2012-07-01' AND st.`datetime` < 'yesterdays-date 23:59:59'

By casting datetime to string (in order to compare) , you're loosing the advantages of indexes...

Comment: wrong. `'2012-07-01'` will be converted to native mysql datetime. it won't be datetime being convered to string.

Comment: `yesterdays-date` just means for today it would execute as `2013-04-14`

Comment: I think putting quotes around the dates is necessary and acceptable. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/95256/469643) is similar and might be something I try